# Android Studio Plugin Exception

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, dagger

I am getting following Android Studio Plugin exception when trying to load project

```
com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: TOPIC [Plugin: com.alayouni.ansiHighlight]
```

This started after I included Dagger 2.11 and enable Annotation Processor and Invalidated cache and then restarted Android Studio,

Now I can't load any Project and its ending up with this same exception. 
I tried:

- Clearing Project build folders
- Re-installing Android Studio but had
  no luck.

I don't think any other plugins that were installed in the studio are interfering as I installed a fresh copy.

Comment: So uninstall com.alayouni.ansiHighlight (ANSI Highlighter)?

Comment: Yes, Now it works,My bad, that was straightforward,
Any idea why this started failing?

Comment: Maybe API change. It will be in the log...

Answer (score 1):

1. Open C:\Users\Administrator.AndroidStudio2.3\config\plugins.
2. Find the file "ansi-highlighter.jar".
3. Delete the file.
4. Restart Android Studio.

source:http://www.aoaoyi.com/archives/774.html