# PluginException: TOPIC[Plugin: com.alayouni.ansiHighlight] | Unable to start IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14, intellij-plugin

I tried to

1. start IntelliJ in normal mode,
2. open my existing projects
3. check out my projects from Version Controls

but all said activities gives me this error:

> Cannot load project:
>   com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException:
>   com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: TOPIC[Plugin:
>   com.alayouni.ansiHighlight]

**Version:**
IntelliJ Community Edition **2016.1.4**

**logs:** Suggest me where do I get logs from

[image: Error while starting IntelliJ]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Plugin Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45533060/android-studio-plugin-exception)

Comment: @Meo Thanks for suggestion, but ansi-highlighter.jar is not available in my env.

Comment: Available? What does that mean?

Comment: ...but ansi-highlighter.jar is not available(doesn't exist) in my env on said location..

Comment: @PratikAmbani See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-and-disabling-plugins.html and https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519. You have this plug-in installed, remove it manually from the plugins directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins can be removed manually from the [plugins directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) or [directly from IDE settings](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-and-disabling-plugins.html).

In your case ansiHighlight plug-in should be removed/disabled.

Comment: I was trying to approach you since morning. :) Issue resolved, thanks buddy :) Seems you're not active on twitter since long.

Comment: I'm active on twitter every day.